# How to disable all keyboard keys except one (or two)

Tags: linux, keyboard

The context for this, in case someone actually knows of a better way to do this, is that I've installed GalliumOS 2.1 on a Lenovo 11e Chromebook. My Chromebook is a 2 in 1 with a touchscreen; however the 2 in 1 functionality does not work as the computer cannot detect being flipped between tablet and laptop mode, although the touchscreen does work.

My intended solution is to write a script that will disable all keyboard keys except the escape key and some other key (possibly right arrow). I intend for the right arrow key to trigger a screen orientation flip between landscape and portrait, and for the escape key to return control of the keyboard and the orientation to end "tablet mode."

So my question is how I would be able to disable all keyboard keys except one or two specific keys, or even better, disable all keys except for specific key combinations that would re-enable all keys or change the screen orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> however the 2 in 1 functionality does not work as the computer cannot detect being flipped between tablet and laptop mode,

So there's no software to react on this event. Which means the first step is to find out what hardware produces that event. Which means getting an overview of what hardware there is, and selecting possible candidates.

> My intended solution is to write a script that will disable all keyboard keys except the escape key and some other key (possibly right arrow).

Quick overview how keyboard processing works under Linux: Key events are picked up by various kernel hardware drivers, and fed into the kernel input layer. This layer maps *scan codes* (physical keys) into *key codes* (standardized keys). The kernel keyboard map then maps key codes into *key symbols*. You can see the output on this layer using `evtest` on `/dev/input/event*` device files.

On top of that, X (Wayland work similarly) has its own drivers collecting keyboard events, among them the `evdev` driver, which collects all events from the kernel input layer. It again maps key codes to key symbols.

There are various ways to disable keys temporaliy, the simplest probably is to "grab" the `/dev/input/eventX` producing them (you can test the effect with `evtest --grab`), filter them in your own custom program, and forward your two non-disabled keys to a new input device to inject them again into the keyboard processing layers. You will need to know how to write e.g. C programs for this solution. You can create new virtual input devices with `/dev/uinput`, see e.g. [here](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput).